# angularUI select dropdown displays data only after entering a character

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am using AngularJS v1.2.15 and [angular-ui / ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select). My select HTML is:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <div class="input-group select2-bootstrap-append">

      <ui-select ng-model="modelOwner.selected" theme="select2" class="form-control">
        <match placeholder="Select Owner">{{$select.selected.name}}</match>
        <choices repeat="item in owner | filter: $select.search">
          <span ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
        </choices>
      </ui-select>

      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button ng-click="modelOwner.selected = undefined" class="btn btn-danger">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
      </span>

    </div>    
  </div>
```

My call in controller is:

```
$scope.modelOwner = {};

OwnersFactory.query({}, function (data) {
  $scope.owner = data;
});
```

My service code:

```
bootstrapApp.factory('OwnersFactory', function ($http,$state,serviceUrl,$resource,$log) {

    return $resource(serviceUrl + 'owner/:id', {}, {
        show: { method: 'GET',  params: {}, isArray: false }
    })
});
```

Now, in my form i can view the values only after entering at least a single character. I want this select dropdown to display values just by clicking on the dropdown (not by entering any character.)

Possible Solution: if i could load my state only after all the AJAX calls have been made.

Please help me out here.

Comment: i dint have a ui-select tag to include...hence the generalized angular-ui tag

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ui-router you can use resolve on each state, so that the call is resolved before initializing the controller

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve